# DynamoDBMapper batchDelete method not working in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Hello I am using the following dependency for reading/writing to DynamoDB in spring boot. **Internally this api calls DynamoDBMapper for performing any of its operations. DynamoDBMapper is apart of the AWS SDK.** **I BELIEVE THERE IS AN ISSUE WITH THE DYNAMODBMAPPER BATCH DELETE CALL IN AWS SDK**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.derjust</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

However, when I invoke the DynamoDBMapper batchDelete method I get the following error

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make final void java.lang.Throwable.setCause(java.lang.Throwable) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @1b083826
```

Here is what the invoking code looks like

```
 List<Matchup> matchups = (List<Matchup>) matchupRepository.findAll();

        DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDBClient);
        try {
            dynamoDBMapper.batchDelete(matchups);
        }

        catch(Exception e) {
            log.error(e.toString());
        }
```

The entity class looks like so

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Sportsbook")
public class Matchup {

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "MatchupId")
    private String matchupId;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "SportsKey")
    private String sportsKey;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "CommenceTime")
    private String commenceTime;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "HomeTeam")
    private String homeTeam;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "AwayTeam")
    private String awayTeam;


    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "PK")
    public String getPK() {
        return "MATCHUP#"+ matchupId;
    }

    public void setPK(String pk) {
        //do nothing
    }

}
```

I noticed all other methods of DynamoDBMapper work except batchDelete. It has the following method signature

```
List<FailedBatch> batchDelete(Iterable<? extends Object> var1);
```

Comment: Remove the `@Data` Lombok annotation from your `Matchup` class and try again

Comment: I removed the @Data annotation and it didn't work.

Comment: I believe there is an issue with the dynamodbmapper batchDelete method

Comment: Are you able to call batchDelete??

Comment: I updated the code to directly use the batchDelete call with just one entity and it didn't work

Comment: List<Matchup> matchups = (List<Matchup>) matchupRepository.findAll();

        DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDBClient);
        try {
           // dynamoDBMapper.batchDelete(Arrays.asList(matchups.get(0)));
            dynamoDBMapper.delete(matchups.get(0));
        }

        catch(Exception e) {
            log.error(e.toString());
        }

Comment: Please update the question :)

Comment: IS DYNAMODBMAPPER NOT APART OF THE AWS SDK??

Comment: The  AWS SDK  for Java V2 is https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/DynamoDbEnhancedClient.html#batchWriteItem-software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.model.BatchWriteItemEnhancedRequest-

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245340/discussion-between-ankit-goel-and-smac2020).

Comment: I will check with the SDK team. I was referring to this Maven repo -- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.derjust/spring-data-dynamodb

Comment: Initially I was using that dependency you referenced. That library internally calls DynamoDBMapper batchDelete. So I decided to cut out the middle man and directly use batchDelete from the aws sdk not wrapping it in the repository anymore

Comment: I am only trying to help devs using the older V1 (or Spring managed APIs - which is not an AWS SDK) to move to what Amazon considers best practice -- which is AWS SDK for Java V2.

Comment: The DynamoDBMapper is in com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:1.11.728. This is not managed by Spring haha this is manage by u guys

Comment: See my answer below - move from V1 -> V2.

Answer (score 0):

You are NOT using the most recent AWS Java API to perform this task. The  **DynamoDBMapper** is part of ***AWS SDK for Java V1 and no longer considered best practice***. Here is the DynamoDBMapper that is part of the V1 DEV Guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-dynamodb-items.html

Amazon States:

***The AWS SDK for Java 2.x is a major rewrite of the version 1.x code base. It’s built on top of Java 8+ and adds several frequently requested features. These include support for non-blocking I/O and the ability to plug in a different HTTP implementation at run time.***

To perform this use case, upgrade from AWS SDK for Java V1 to V2 and use and the **Enhanced Client** as explained in the *AWS Java V2 DEV Guide*:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/dynamodb-enhanced-client.html

Here is a code example that shows H**OW TO Delete batch items** using the Enhanced Client. First - assume you have a Customer table with this data and you want to delete batch records.

[image]

Here is the full code example with the Enhanced Client.

```
package com.example.dynamodb;

// snippet-start:[dynamodb.java2.mapping.batchdelete.import]

import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.DynamoDbEnhancedClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.DynamoDbTable;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.TableSchema;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.model.BatchWriteItemEnhancedRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.model.DeleteItemEnhancedRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.model.WriteBatch;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.DynamoDbException;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.Key;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
// snippet-end:[dynamodb.java2.mapping.batchdelete.import]

/*
 * Before running this code example, create an Amazon DynamoDB table named Customer with these columns:
 *   - id - the id of the record that is the key
 *   - custName - the customer name
 *   - email - the email value
 *   - registrationDate - an instant value when the item was added to the table
 *
 * Also, ensure that you have set up your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For information, see this documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */
public class EnhancedBatchDeleteItems {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = ProfileCredentialsProvider.create();
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        DynamoDbClient ddb = DynamoDbClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                .build();

        DynamoDbEnhancedClient enhancedClient = DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder()
                .dynamoDbClient(ddb)
                .build();

        deleteBatchRecords(enhancedClient);
        ddb.close();
    }

    // snippet-start:[dynamodb.java2.mapping.batchdelete.main]
    public static void deleteBatchRecords(DynamoDbEnhancedClient enhancedClient) {

        try {
            DynamoDbTable<Customer> mappedTable = enhancedClient.table("Customer", TableSchema.fromBean(Customer.class));
            Key key1 = Key.builder()
                    .partitionValue("id110")
                    .build();

            Key key2 = Key.builder()
                    .partitionValue("id120")
                    .build();

            BatchWriteItemEnhancedRequest request =  BatchWriteItemEnhancedRequest.builder()
                    .writeBatches(WriteBatch.builder(Customer.class)
                                    .mappedTableResource(mappedTable)
                                    .addDeleteItem(DeleteItemEnhancedRequest.builder()
                                            .key(key1)
                                            .build())
                                    .build(),
                            WriteBatch.builder(Customer.class)
                                    .mappedTableResource(mappedTable)
                                    .addDeleteItem(DeleteItemEnhancedRequest.builder()
                                            .key(key2)
                                            .build())
                                    .build())
                    .build();

            // Delete these two items from the table.
            enhancedClient.batchWriteItem(request);
            System.out.println("Records deleted");

        } catch (DynamoDbException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    // snippet-end:[dynamodb.java2.mapping.batchdelete.main]
}
```

More information here:

https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/DynamoDbEnhancedClient.html#batchWriteItem-software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.model.BatchWriteItemEnhancedRequest-

Now we are left with these items:

[image]

Finally, you can find the **Customer** class, the POM file, etc in [AWS Java V2 Github here](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/dynamodb).

Comment: Does not answer my question

Comment: I answered your question Of How to Delete Batch Data by showing you how to use the Enhanced Client -- which is AWS SDK  for Java V2 and which AWS Recommends using over V1. V1 is older API and Not Best practice.  Upgrade from  DynamoDBMapper  to Enhanced Client.